# SQl Difference in date

Tags: sql, sql-date-functions, sqldatetime

I need find difference in two `date` in years
but years should be in decimal
example 
i need to find difference between `16-jun-2010` to `30-Sep-2014`

and it should be `4.30` yrs

i try following way 
select DATEDIFF(YY,'16-jun-2010','30-sep-2014') as YearsOfServices

it give me 4 only

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The difference between those two dates will never be 4.5 years

Comment: right please correct the question

Comment: I edited my question i hope now it clear

Comment: Even with the edit, it's completely unclear to me how you arrive at `.50` after the decimal point. It's not half a year between June and September. And it's more than 50 days between the two, which are the only two possibilities that sprung to mind to me (and the latter would be quite a baffling concept), so please *explain* the logic of this calculation to us.

Comment: Answer will be 4.5 IF date is '16-jun-2010' and '30-dec-2014'

Comment: yes you are correct Rita and i got my answer Round(DATEDIFF(DD,'16-jun-2010','30-sep-2014')/365.0,1) as Datediff                 thanks for help

Answer (score 6):

The built in function `datediff()` does is compute the number of period boundaries crossed between to dates.

```
datediff(yy,'16 jun 2014','30 Sep 2015')

returns 1
```

You'll get more accurate result if you compute the difference between the two dates in days and divide them by the mean length of a calendar year in days over a 400 year span (365.2425):

```
datediff(day,{start-date},{end-date},) / 365.2425
```

For example,

```
select datediff(day,'1 Jan 2000' ,'18 April 2014') / 365.2425
```

`return 14.29461248` — just round it to the desired precision.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, '16-jun-2010','30-Sep-2014')/365.0 AS DiffDate
```

Either you should try

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(mm, '16-jun-2010','30-sep-2014')/12.0 AS DiffDate
```

Comment: and it right bcz there is 4 year and only three months,if there is 4 yr and 6 month that time answer will be around 4.5 year

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
Declare @a Date
declare @b date
set @a ='07-01-2013'
set @b='08-02-2014'




 select  (DATEDIFF(DAY,@a,@b))/convert(numeric,365)
```

Answer (score 0):

i got my answer Round(DATEDIFF(DD,'16-jun-2010','30-sep-2014')/365.0,1) as  as Datediff thanks for help